# (Spring Boot) <form> doesn't go to the 'action' url after submitted

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I've made a `<form>` of post method. When running the project, the url doesn't go inside the post controller when I click the submit button. To find out what is the matter, I've changed the 'action' property value of the `<form>` tag into an existing page's url. Even so, it doesn't go to that page. So I think the matter is that the submit event doesn't happen. Why does this happen and what should I do to get it work?

HTML code:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <form class="mdl-card mdl-shadow-2dp mdl-cell--12-col" method="post" action="${action}" role="form">
        <#include "content/form/${view}.ftl">
    </form>
    <div class="mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid btn-wrapper">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-cell--12-col" type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView join() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("form");
        mv.addObject("layout", "form");
        mv.addObject("view", "createMember");
        mv.addObject("viewmsg", "Sign In");
        mv.addObject("action", "/member/join");
        mv.addObject("modelName", "member");
        Member member = new Member();
        mv.addObject("member", member);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        logger.debug("aaaa");
        Member member = new Member();
        member.setId(id);
        member.setName(name);
        member.setPassword(password);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        try {
            memberService.create(member);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            mv.addObject("layout", "form");
            mv.addObject("view", "createMember");
            mv.addObject("viewmsg", "Sign In");
            mv.addObject("action", "/member/join");
            mv.addObject("member", member);
            mv.addObject("modelName", "member");
            mv.addObject("error", e.getMessage());

            return mv;
        }

        mv.setViewName("home");
        mv.addObject("view", "home");
        mv.addObject("member", member);
        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: Your submit button needs to be inside the form, unless you want to  handle the click event and trigger it from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your action value to double-check on the target endpoint. Secondly, move the `submit` button inside the `form`.